# If $W$ is a subspace of $V$,then $\dim(W)+\dim(W^0)=\dim(V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

From the structure of this all i getting is that

> If $V$ an n-dimensional vector space with an ordered basis
>   $\beta=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)$ among them (say) first $k$-vectors
>   form the basis for $W$.Let $\beta*=\{f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots,f_n\}$ be the
>   dual basis for $V$, then the functional elements of$\beta* $
>   corresponding to last $n-k$ vectors of $\beta$ forms the basis for
>   $W^0$

Showing $\{f_{k+1},f_{k+2},f_{k+3},\ldots,f_n\}$ is a basis for $W^0$ .

We know that,inorder to show $T=\{f_{k+1},f_{k+2},f_{k+3},\ldots,f_n\}$ to be a basis for $W^0$ it is sufficient to show that $\operatorname{span} T=W^0$.Since $T$ is a subset of $\beta*  $ so $T $ is linearly independent. Since $W^0$ is a subset of $V*$,every element of $f$ in $W^0$ we could write as a linear combinations of elements of $\beta*$.

From,here I lost the track.

Comment: annhilator of $W$

Comment: $W^0$ looks to be the kernel of the protection onto $W$.

Comment: @jdods:yeah,you can say so.

Comment: @mvw:sketch of the proof is similar to that of dimension theorem,but the arguments involved in it are different

Comment: $T$ is a basis for $W$ but spans $W^0$? Seems odd...

Comment: jdods:Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: It seems like there is almost nothing to show here. You have $\dim(W)=k$, and $\dim(W^0)=n-k$ by the highlighted statement/definition. Am I missing something? It's a bit unclear exactly what you are wanting to show from the statement of your question. Also there may be another $W$ that should be $W^0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39470/discussion-between-pk-styles-and-jdods).